# Sinon mock a function that accepts a callback parameter

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, sinon, mysql2

I have a Connection class used to create a Mysql connection pool and execute a transaction. The class has method `transaction` that accepts a callback function as a parameter. The callback passed to the `transaction` function will be `mysql2.query` Inserts.

Connection class:

```
const mysql2 = require('mysql2/promise');

class Connection {
    constructor(options = {}) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    createPool () {
        this.pool = mysql2.createPool({
            host: this.options.host,
            user: this.options.user,
            database:  'my_db',
            ssl: 'Amazon RDS',
            password: this.options.password,
            authPlugins: {
                mysql_clear_password: () => () => Buffer.from(this.options.password + '\0')
            }
        });
    }

    async transaction(callback) {
        const connection = await this.pool.getConnection();
        await connection.beginTransaction();

        try {
            await callback(connection);
            await connection.commit();
        } catch (err) {
            await connection.rollback();
            throw err;
        } finally {
            connection.release();
        }
    }
}
module.exports = { Connection };
```

Here is how the `transaction` function is used.

```
   await conn.transaction(async connection => {
      await connection.query(sql1,[values1]);
      await connection.query(sql2,[values2]);
      await connection.query(sql3,[values3]);
    });
```

My goal is to mock the `async transaction` method, but I'm having a difficult time with the callback. Here is what I have tried based on some answers to similar posts and reading the sinon documentation.
https://sinonjs.org/releases/v9.2.0/stubs/

```
it('should test transaction function in Connection', async () => {
    jest.setTimeout(30000);
    const results = { affectedRows: 1 };
    const poolStub = {
        getConnection: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
        query: sinon.stub().returns(results),
        beginTransaction: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
        release: sinon.stub(),
    };
    
    const createPoolStub = sinon.stub(mysql2, 'createPool').returns(poolStub);
    const conn = new conns.Connection();
    await conn.createPool();
    const actual = await conn.transaction('select 1 + 1 as solution',[]);

    expect(actual).to.be.eql(1);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(createPoolStub);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(poolStub.getConnection);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(poolStub.query, 'select 1 + 1 as solution');
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(poolStub.release);
});
```

Notice that I am trying to return `results = { affectedRows: 1 };` when the `query` method is called. However this is not working correctly and the query attempt simply times out.

```
: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 30000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.
```

---

As requested, here is the handler code which shows how the Connection class is used, including how it is imported and initialized

```
const utils = require('./utils');
const conns = require('./connection');

let response = {
  statusCode: 200,
  body: {
    message: 'SQS event processed.',
  },
};

exports.handler = async(event) => {
  try {
    const values1 = [];
    const values2= [];
    const values3 = [];
    for (const currentMessage of event.Records) {
      const data = JSON.parse(currentMessage.body);
      console.log(`Processing Received data`);

      const {record} = data;

      if (record.id == 100) {
        values1.push([record.field1,record.field2, record.field3, Date.now(), Date.now(), 'service-user', 'service-user']);
      }
      if (record.id == 200) {
        values2.push([record.field1,record.field2, record.field3, Date.now(), Date.now(), 'service-user', 'service-user']);
      }
      if (record.id == 300) {
        values3.push([record.field1,record.field2, record.field3, Date.now(), Date.now(), 'service-user', 'service-user']);
      }
    }

    const options = {
      host: 'my-host',
      user: 'service-user'
    };

    const token = utils.getToken(options);
    options.password = token;

    const conn = new conns.Connection(options);
    conn.createPool();

    const sql1 = 'INSERT INTO table1(field1, field2, field4, created_date, modified_date, created_by, modified_by) VALUES ?';
    const sql2 = 'INSERT INTO table2(field1, field2, field4, created_date, modified_date, created_by, modified_by) VALUES ?';
    const sql3 = 'INSERT INTO table3(field1, field2, field4, created_date, modified_date, created_by, modified_by) VALUES ?';

    await conn.transaction(async connection => {
      await connection.query(sql1,[values1]);
      await connection.query(sql2,[values2]);
      await connection.query(sql3,[values3]);
    });


    await conn.pool.end();
    console.log("Connection ended")

  } catch (e) {
    console.log('There was an error while processing', { errorMessage: e});

    response = {
      statusCode: 400,
      body: e
    }
  }

  return response;
};
```

Comment: Please provide the code to be tested which uses the `conn.transaction` method, including how the `Connection` class imported  and initialized

Comment: I'd like to test the `transaction` method itself

Comment: I have edited the post to include the lambda handler which shows the import and initialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is unit test solution:

`connection.test.js`:

```js
const conns = require('./connection');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const mysql2 = require('mysql2/promise');

describe('64255673', () => {
  it('should test transaction function in Connection', async () => {
    const results = { affectedRows: 1 };
    const connectionStub = {
      beginTransaction: sinon.stub(),
      commit: sinon.stub(),
      rollback: sinon.stub(),
      release: sinon.stub(),
    };
    const poolStub = {
      getConnection: sinon.stub().returns(connectionStub),
      query: sinon.stub().returns(results),
    };
    const createPoolStub = sinon.stub(mysql2, 'createPool').returns(poolStub);

    const conn = new conns.Connection();
    conn.createPool();
    const callback = sinon.stub();
    await conn.transaction(callback);

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(createPoolStub);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(poolStub.getConnection);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(connectionStub.beginTransaction);
    sinon.assert.calledOnceWithExactly(callback, connectionStub);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(connectionStub.commit);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(connectionStub.release);
  });
});
```

unit test result with coverage report:

```
  64255673
    ✓ should test transaction function in Connection


  1 passing (13ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |   71.43 |      100 |      60 |   76.92 |                   
 connection.js |   71.43 |      100 |      60 |   76.92 | 16,29-30          
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

You can use `stub.rejects(value);` to make `await connection.commit()` rejected. Then you can test the code in `catch` block.

Comment: this is great answer for testing the `Connection.transaction` function, but how would i test the lambda handler function that calls `Connection.transaction`?

    `await conn.transaction(async connection => {...}`